# Help Resolving formula syntax error

Tags: formula, hyperlink

I am working on a formula to display a hyperlink based on status and 1 condition where only a certain profile can display the hyperlink.

So far I have the formula below:

IF (
AND (ISPICKVAL( Status , "Referred UW"),$User.ProfileId = 'profileid'),
OR (
ISPICKVAL( Status , "In Progress"),
ISPICKVAL( Status , "Quoted"),
ISPICKVAL( Status , "Referred TMR"),
ISPICKVAL( Status , "Referred TMR Manager"),
ISPICKVAL( Status , "Referral Approved") ),
HYPERLINK("hyperlink example",
"Retrieve Link", "_blank")
, "User unable to retrieve link")

However I am getting the following syntax error:
Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4

Can anyone help to see where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If` function should have only three parameter `IF(logic,TRUE,FALSE)`. So, your code should be as

```
  IF(
    AND (
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred UW"),
        $User.ProfileId = 'profileid',
        OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "In Progress"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Quoted"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred TMR"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred TMR Manager"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referral Approved")
    )
    ),
    HYPERLINK("hyperlink example", "Retrieve Link", "_blank")
    ,
    "User unable to retrieve link"
)
```

Comment: Hi Prathyusha, thank you for the response. This has passed the syntax errors but now it's displaying the false parameter for all records even with the correct status

Comment: Could you please tell me your condition. Should we display condition when Status is Referred UW and some certain profile id???

Comment: Yes that is correct, for the other status values, I need to display the hyperlink regardless of profile but for status = Referred UW, I need to limit the hyperlink to only that profile

Comment: Try this,  
  IF(       
        IF($User.ProfileId = 'profileid',
   ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred UW"),
   OR(
            ISPICKVAL(Status, "In Progress"),
            ISPICKVAL(Status, "Quoted"),
            ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred TMR"),
            ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred TMR Manager"),
            ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referral Approved")
        ))
  
        ,
  HYPERLINK("hyperlink example", "Retrieve Link", "_blank")
        ,
        "User unable to retrieve link"
    )

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. Really Appreciate your help

Comment: No Problem :) Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

These types of error are always easier to spot if you tab everything out:

You currently have:

```
IF(
    AND (
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred UW"),
        $User.ProfileId = 'profileid'
    ),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "In Progress"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Quoted"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred TMR"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referred TMR Manager"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Referral Approved")
    ),
    HYPERLINK("hyperlink example", "Retrieve Link", "_blank") ,
    "User unable to retrieve link"
)
```

You have one condition which checks the combination of profile and status, then you seem to be trying to merge in other status values in an unsupported way. Difficult to guess what you were going for, but if you wanted it to be the combination of that profile with *any* of those statuses, the correct logical structure would be:

```
AND(
    $User.Profile.Name = "Use Name Not Id",
    OR(...)
)
```

Note also that you will save a significant number of compiled characters by switching to `CASE` when checking if a single field is any of a number of possible values.

```
1 = CASE(
    Status,
    "Referred UW", 1,
    "In Progress", 1,
    "etc.", 1,
    0
)
```

Comment: Adrian, thank you for your response, much appreciate. I am trying to display a hyperlink to user based on the quote status but I have a condition that for status " Referred UW", be limited to 1 profile. Originally I was using a case formula but as soon as I try to add the above condition, I can't seem to get past the syntax errors. Previously tried using case but still come across the issue